# how to add check constraints for date columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting this error

> ORA-02438: Column check constraint cannot reference other columns

when I am performing this query

```
alter table Issue
modify Issue_Date not null check (Issue_Date <= sys_date);
```

as well as I have to add this condition also (`issue_date<return_date`);

and when I tried this

```
alter table Issue
add constraint ck_Issue_Date not null check (Issue_Date <= sys_date);
```

> ERROR ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Comment: Remove the underscore in sysdate

Comment: With the help of virtual columns (version 11 or higher), you can use sysdate in check constraints: http://rwijk.blogspot.nl/2007/12/check-constraints-with-sysdate.html

Comment: Getting this error if I remove the underscore:

ORA-02436: date or system variable wrongly specified in CHECK constraint

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are wanting to reference the Oracle `SYSDATE` function, not a column named `sys_date`.

Unfortunately, the conditions in a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` cannot reference the SYSDATE function.

To get the database enforce this type of restriction on the value of a column, that would require a `TRIGGER`.

For example, something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_issue_issue_date_biu
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Issue
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF (NEW.Issue_Date <= SYSDATE) THEN
      NULL;
   ELSE
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Invalid: Issue_Date is NULL or >SYSDATE');
   END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You tried to mix up inline column level constraint and table level constraint (for more than 1 column). Please simply split them on 2 statements:

```
alter table Issue
  modify Issue_Date not null;

alter table Issue
  add constraint ck_Issue_Date check (Issue_Date <= sys_date);

alter table Issue
  add constraint ck_Issue_Date2 check (issue_date<return_date);
```